# How many Allied lieutenants were killed during the D-Day beach landings?

Tags: dday

How many Allied lieutenants were killed during the D-Day beach landings?  There seemed to be 2 lieutenants boarded in each landing craft.

Comment: Which beach? Over a third of all casualties were on Omaha Beach, just one of the five landing beaches, particularly in the first wave. Also: why are you asking the question? Knowing that will allow us to determine the required accuracy. In the case of beach landings, with most casualties inflicted at considerable range by non-snipers, there's little reason to expect casualties to vary significantly across ranks.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: [honorstates.org lists 228 US Lieutenant casualties on June 6th, 1944](https://www.honorstates.org/index.php?do=q&date=06-06-1944&rank=lieutenant&p=1). They would not all be due to D-Day, you'll have to look at each of them.

Comment: The [Commonwealth War Graves Commission lists 115 lieutenants](https://www.cwgc.org/find-records/find-war-dead/search-results/?Surname=&Forename=&Initials=&ServiceNum=&Regiment=&Rank=lieutenant&DateDeathFromDay=1&DateDeathFromMonth=January&DateDeathFromYear=&DateDeathToDay=1&DateDeathToMonth=January&DateDeathToYear=&DateOfDeath=06%2F06%2F1944&CountryCommemoratedIn=null&Cemetery=&Unit=&SecondaryRegiment=&AgeOfDeath=0&Honours=null&AdditionalInfo=) and sub-lieutenants and flight lieutenants and lieutenant-colonels, the large majority but not all of whom were buried in France